# Parts per million

Tags: ingredients, water

How do you calculate parts per million (or billion) from grams and volume?

I ask this in relation to figureing out how to translate water report information into the recommended ranges of certain brewing salts for emulating water profiles.

Comment: This answer will undoubtedly involve mols.
/gets out the popcorn and chemistry text book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually its moles free, so no chemistry text or periodic table needed.
I just looked it up and did the math.

1ppm means one part in one million parts.

For instance then.  1 milligram in 1 kilogram.  (1kg=1000g=1,000,000mg)

The more relavant application for brewing would be mg of solid (CaCl2) in a liter of water.
Its tricky because first you need to assume that 1 gram=1milliliter of water.

So 1 ppm is 1mg/Liter via the following:

1mg=0.001ml
1L=1000mL

0.001/1000 = 1/1,000,000 or 1ppm

Answer (score 0):

Though, I don't know the actual math (and disappointed that it doesn't involve calculating molarity), I did find [this calculator](http://www.unitconversion.org/unit_converter/concentration-solution.html) to be helpful (if not saturated with Google ads).